# Customized accounts software - Ageing report in PHP

Tags: mysql

I am developing custom accounting software for customer. I need to develop the ageing report problem faced issue for sundry debtors - opening amount in Dr and only receipt voucher no sales done. In statement report showed the exact balance figure. But from my ageing query I am unable to show the opening balance parties.

| orderid | Party Name | Date | Voucher Type | Dr | Cr | AdjAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Murugan | 2021-04-01 | Op | -3999885.00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Murugan | 2021-04-23 | Receipt | 0 | 1000000.00 | 0 |
| 2 | Murugan | 2021-04-26 | Receipt | 0 | 500000.00 | 0 |
| 2 | Murugan | 2021-06-11 | Receipt | 0 | 500000.00 | 0 |
| 99 | Murugan |  | **Closing Balce** | **1999885.00** | 0 | 0 |

My ageing report not shows because I stuck in my query.

```
SELECT d.PartyLedgerName AS PartyName
        , SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), d.vDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 30, ROUND(ABS(d.AdjAmt), 2), 0)) AS age00_30
        , SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), d.vDate) BETWEEN 31 AND 60, ROUND(ABS(d.AdjAmt), 2), 0)) AS age00_60
        , SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), d.vDate) BETWEEN 61 AND 90, ROUND(ABS(d.AdjAmt), 2), 0)) AS age00_90
        , SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), d.vDate) BETWEEN 91 AND 120, ROUND(ABS(d.AdjAmt), 2), 0)) AS age00_120
        , SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), d.vDate) > 120, ROUND(ABS(d.AdjAmt), 2), 0)) AS age121
FROM acc_statement AS d
WHERE d.VoucherType IN ("Sales")
GROUP BY d.PartyLedgerName
ORDER BY d.PartyLedgerName ASC
```

Sorry for missed by expected Result. I need output like

| Party Name | age00_30 | age31_60 | age61_90 | age91_120 | age121 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Murugan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1999885.00 | 0 |

This was I need the output.

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected result of this query, based on the sample table data you've shown. Or is what you've shown us the expected result (in which case please also provide the raw table data it's derived from) - it's not clear?

Comment: Please add it to the question (using the "edit" button) and format it properly so we can read it without any difficulty. Thanks.